# How to show error page in joomla if page is not found ?

Tags: joomla

I am completely new in joomla.

I have website e.g mysite.com

When I visit this site it's opening the url like bellow :

> mysite.com/index.php/de/

When I go to this link

> mysite.com/index.php/de/abskds

It's successfully showing 404 page.

But how can I show this 404 error page when someone go to bellow link:

> mysite.com/abskds

Many thanks :)

Comment: What is it showing now?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in one of two ways

#### Method 1

Open your configuration file `(configuration.php)` and look for the line 
`public $error_reporting = ‘default’;`
You will then need to change this to the following based on your needs:

- `E_ALL | E_STRICT` – All errors, warnings, notices, and strict
  standards will be displayed on the website
- `E_ALL` – All errors, warnings, notices will be displayed on the
  website
- `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` – All errors, warnings, but no notices will be
  displayed on the website
- `E_ALL & ~(E_NOTICE|E_WARNING)` – All
  Errors. No warnings or notices    will be displayed on the website;
- `0` – No error reporting at all

#### Method 2

In your Admin Panel, navigate through `Global Configuration >> Server tab >> Error Reporting`. Choose an option as follows:

- **System Default:** Joomla will inherit error reporting defaults set in the server (usually in php.ini file).
- **Simple:** Overrides server settings to give a basic report with warnings only about the fatal errors.
- **Maximum (Recommended):** Overrides server settings to gives full report with all the errors, warnings, notices, deprecated functions call, strict standards on the website.
- **None:** switched off

Comment: Probably you have not understood the question. He asked why he is not getting 404 error when someone visits mysite.com/abskds url.

Answer (score 0):

Go to administrator.
In global configuration you'll see a SEO Settings.
Search Engine Friendly URLs Yes
And
Use URL Rewriting Yes - Follow instruction how to modify files according wich server you use.

Warning when you enable these all link with index.php will be modifies.

http://mywebsite/index.php/de
will go to:
http://mywebsite/de

Hope these help.

Answer (score 0):

First go to admin panel > Global Configuration and turn mode_rewrite on.
Then go to your root folder (Joomla! Installation Folder) and rename the `htaccess.txt` to `.htaccess`